# Testing an ActiveRecord Model Method with Shoulda and RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, shoulda, matcher

I understand how to use the prebuilt Shoulda matchers out of the box (`validate_presence_of`, `validate_uniqueness_of` etc), but how should I test things it doesn't have prebuilt matchers for?

For example, say I have a method on my User model called `full_name` looks like this:

```
  def full_name
    "#{forename} #{surname}"
  end
```

How would I test that with Shoulda? Or should I just fall back to using standard Rspec with Factory Girl for things like this?

Answer (score 1):

Shoulda is to add some helpful matchers to simplify things. If nothing to simplify you don't need it.

You don't need either Shoulda or FactoryGirl in this simple case

```
context "#full_name" do
  it "works" do
    user = User.new
    user.forename = "Bob"
    user.surname  = "Smith"
    expect(user.full_name).to eq("Bob Smith")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Thought I was missing something.